# How To get rid of "AttributeError"

Tags: python, attributeerror, traceback

[the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1rnr.png)

[Here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVPzz.png)

Please any help on how to fix this, i'm trying to write a code ARP spoofer

Comment: is should be `summary` instead of `sumarry`. Also provide the snippets as code and not as links to external images please.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote sumarry with two r
is that the error?

Comment: That was where the problem was...Thanks so much

Comment: Thanks so much it fixed it..but now it shows ?? instead of my IP